# Better way to display list in ionic app

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using `collection-repeat` directive for displaying my data. But I'm not getting proper alignments. I've tried setting the `col-xx` for each column. Still the results are somewhat not aligned properly. Below is my code for displaying the list data:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-center"><strong>Room No.</strong></div>
      <div class="col col-center"><strong>Date</strong></div>
      <div class="col col-center"><strong>Start</strong></div>
      <div class="col col-center"><strong>End</strong></div>
      <div class="col col-center"><strong>Can't make it?</strong></div>
      <!--<div class="col"><strong>User</strong></div>-->
    </div>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item collection-repeat="reservation in ownReservedRoomsList">
      <ion-card>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-center">{{reservation.Room_ID}}</div>
          <div class="col col-center">{{reservation.Dt}}</div>
          <div class="col col-center">{{reservation.StartTime}}</div>
          <div class="col col-center">{{reservation.EndTime}}</div>
          <!--<div class="col">{{room.Login_ID}}</div>-->
          <div class="col col-center">
            <button class="button button-small icon-left ion-trash-a button-assertive"
                    ng-click="cancelReservation(reservation._id)">
              Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

In the above code, `ownReservedRoomsList` is the list that contains the records.

Below is the output that I'm getting:

[image]

Is there any other better way to display the list data in ionic or any CSS that makes the output of `collection-repeat` more aesthetic?

Comment: You're centering items that are not of the same width. They really can't align. I'd choose classes that use left or right justifications instead.

Comment: Also, this really looks like a place where a table would make the most sense.